# In my php project when I clicked on logout, I am redirecting at home page, and if I click back button I am getting back in account page

Tags: php, session, cookies

In my php project when I clicked on logout, I am redirecting at home page, and if I click back button I am getting back in account page, I dont wont to let anyone to come back in account once they clicked logout, which is the best way to do this?. please rply. Thnx

Comment: You really need to add more details on how your authentication method works.

Comment: You need to unset session on your home page after logged out.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you're not destroying the session, hence allowing the users to return to the 'accounts page'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroy the session:

```
session_unset();//Unset all session variables
session_destroy();
```

And maybe redirect users if they don't have a valid session. Add in your header something like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){
//Go to some other page
header("Location:$homepage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($_SESSION['variable_name']);
```

or you can also destroy the session to logout.

```
session_destroy();
```